# Share the same Entity Framework dbContext over more then one DAL classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I would like that more then one DAL Classes will use the same Entity Framework dbContext from the BLL in order to work with transactions and to avoid creating dbContext all the time.

Therefore, i am using my ContextHolder class that will hold there the reference for the dbContext. i would like to do something like this:

```
using (var contextHolder= new DAL.contextHolder()) //Here i create an instance for the real DBContext and pass it as a reference to every dal function i have

            {

                var dalAdminUsers = new JungleDAL.AdminUsers(contextHolder); 
                dalAdminUsers.DoSomething();

                var dalCustomers = new JungleDAL.Customers(contextHolder);
                dalCustomers .DoSomething();

            }// Here i want to dispose my ContextHolder that should dispose in his turn the DBContext.
```

Is it the right way to share same Entity Framework dbContext from the BLL functions?

Comment: do you use Dependency Injection?

Comment: long-living DbContext instances tend to be a performance hit itself. If you need to have the same context instance because of entry lifetime issues, use Dependency Injection instead.